# File upload not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a file select component that allows the user to upload and delete files for the front and back sides of a document. It works fine for the first attempt but once the user deletes the uploaded file, they are not able to upload a file again. The 'upload' button stops working in a reliable manner.

**Code:**

Handle file upload

```
  const [frontSideFile, setFrontSideFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [backSideFile, setBackSideFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [frontSideUploadStatus, setFrontSideUploadStatus] =
    useState<string>("");
  const [backSideUploadStatus, setBackSideUploadStatus] = useState<string>("");
```

Frontside

```
  const handleFrontSideUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file: File = e.target.files[0];

      if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES) {
        setFrontSideUploadStatus(
          "Selected file is too large. Please choose a smaller file"
        );
        //clear input field to allow re-selection of a file
        e.target.value = "";
      } else {
        setFrontSideFile(file);
        // Clear any previous error message
        setFrontSideUploadStatus("");
      }
    }
```

Backside

```
  const handleBackSideUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file: File = e.target.files[0];

      if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES) {
        setBackSideUploadStatus(
          "Selected file is too large. Please choose a smaller file"
        );
        e.target.value = "";
      } else {
        setBackSideFile(file);
        // Clear any previous error message
        setBackSideUploadStatus("");
      }
    }
  };
```

Handle file deletion

```
  const handleDelete = (
    setFile: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<File | null>>
  ) => {
    setFile(null);
  };
```

Component

```
//Front
              <div>
                <label
                  htmlFor="frontSideFileInput"
                >
                  Upload front side
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="frontSideFileInput"
                  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf" //specify allowed file types
                  onChange={(e) => handleFrontSideUpload(e)}
                  style={{ display: "none" }} //hide the input element
                />
                {frontSideFile && (
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      Selected: {frontSideFile.name}
                    </p>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => handleDelete(setFrontSideFile)}
                      className=""
                    >
                      <TbTrash className="text-red-400" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                )}
                {frontSideUploadStatus && (
                  <p className="text-red-500">{frontSideUploadStatus}</p>
                )}
              </div>

//Back

       <div>
                <label
                  htmlFor="backSideFileInput"
                >
                  Upload back side
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="backSideFileInput"
                  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf"
                  onChange={(e) => handleBackSideUpload(e)}
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                />
                {backSideFile && (
                  <div>
                    <p>
                      Selected: {backSideFile.name}
                    </p>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => handleDelete(setBackSideFile)}
                    >
                      <TbTrash />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                )}
                {backSideUploadStatus && (
                  <p>{backSideUploadStatus}</p>
                )}
              </div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the given code. Can reupload files both with and without deleting a previously selected file.

Comment: @AliNauman, you're saying the code works just fine on your end?

Comment: I'm adding in the rest of the code that includes a second upload button. I've tested it and it's still not working properly. On and off.

Comment: Even with your updated code, I cannot reproduce the problem. I am also editing your code to make it easier for others to run it.